# Is there any way to make just *one* app change DPI scaling automatically when moved from one display to another?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I suspect this is impossible, but I want to verify. I have one large 1440 display and one moderately-sized 1080 hooked up to the same tower. I don't want to turn on Windows' monitor-wide scaling feature, since there are plenty of apps where I'd like to actually take advantage of the 1440 display and I don't want them blown up. But there are also plenty of apps--like Firefox--where text and interface are quite small on the higher-res monitor.

I know how to change the scaling for just one display (in display settings) or just one app (in the .exe's properties.) Is there any way at all to change the scaling for *just one app on just one display,* such that it will rescale correctly if dragged from one monitor onto another?

(Or, have I misunderstood the monitor-wide scaling feature? If I turn it on, then the things I want the high resolution for, like games or video, will no longer be displaying at full resolution because of the scaling--right? Or is that not how it works?)

Comment: (Proper) scaling doesn’t mean the resolution is reduced at all. Think Retina displays.

Comment: Also: I've just realized this is even more important because the windows by-monitor scaling option isn't suitable for my needs; it doesn't offer anything between 100% and 125% scaling. those are too small and too big respectively...110% is perfect.